# Feynman diagrams with feynarts

Tags: diagrams, feynman

I'm trying to draw Feynman diagrams with the feynarts.sty package for LaTex. The problem is that if I write the following code:

```
\begin{feynartspicture}(150,150)(1,1)
   \FADiagram{}
   \FAProp(0.,10.)(6.,10.)(0.,){/Straight}{0}
   \FALabel(3.,9.18)[t]{$1$}
   \FAProp(20.,10.)(14.,10.)(0.,){/Straight}{0}
   \FALabel(17.,10.82)[b]{$2$}
   \FAProp(6.,10.)(14.,10.)(0.8,){/Straight}{0}
   \FALabel(10.,5.98)[t]{$3$}
   \FAProp(6.,10.)(14.,10.)(-0.8,){/Straight}{0}
   \FALabel(10.,14.02)[b]{$4$}
   \FAVert(6.,10.){0}
   \FAVert(14.,10.){0}
\end{feynartspicture}
```

I get this:

[image]

Instead of this:

[image]

In practice I get only the label of the propagators but not the propagators. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Ideally we'd like to see a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv) rather than code snippets.

Comment: I just downloaded the arXiv [article](http://arxiv.org/abs/0711.1345) and compiled it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my own problem. I just need to add

```
% !TEX TS-program = latex
```

in the first line of the LaTeX file.