# Drawing Feynman Diagram in Latex with feynarts.sty

Tags: diagrams, feynman

I am trying to draw Feynman diagram with feynarts.sty in MikTek2.9.

However, I get diagram with nothing only label.

This is the same problem as [Feynman diagrams with feynarts](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/278165/feynman-diagrams-with-feynarts/278175#278175?newreg=118b5cecf4ab447fa2ca02678256cbfb) but his solution doesn't work for me.

Any other solutions?

Thanks

Comment: I recommend [`tikz-feynman`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tikz-feynman) instead.

Comment: @HenriMenke I have tried tikz-feynman already and it's work!!! However, I get new problem about size of the diagram. I get very small diagram and small, medium and large don't work.

Comment: I’m glad that my suggestion helped you.  If you can extend your question by a short but compilable example illustrating your problem, I’ll be happy to provide you an answer.

Comment: @HenriMenke First, I use \feynmandiagram[horizontal=a to b] and I found that the diagram is too small then I change to \feynmandiagram[large, horizontal=a to b]. However, nothing is changed. I also try the code in the manual which compare 3 size (small, medium, and large) but I also get the same size for 3 diagrams.

Answer (score 1):

You should change your compiler to `latex` instead of `pdflatex`, `xelatex`, or `lualatex`. then you can generate the diagrams normally.